# Python django image upload is not working

Tags: python, django, image, file-upload

**Python Django image upload is not working when I am adding data and click on submit button not give a any response and also not upload any data in the database.**

models.py
fisrst of all i add model file.

```
# Create your models here.
from django.db import models
class Car(models.Model):

    carname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    carmodel = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    carimage = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    price=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    average=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    gear=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    passengers = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Insurance=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        db_table="car"
```

forms.py
then i create a form.py.

```
from django import forms
from  carapp.models import Car

class CarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Car
        fields="__all__"
```

**also add this two line in settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py
then i give a path of method.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from carapp import carviews
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #this is for admin user
    path('savecar',carviews.savecar),
    path('showcar', carviews.showcar)
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

carviews.py

then I created an API method.

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from carapp.forms import CarForm
from carapp.models import Car
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, InvalidPage

def savecar(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form= CarForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.save()
                return redirect("/showcar")
            except:
                pass
    else:
        form = CarForm()
    return render(request,"savecar.html",{'form':form})

def showcar(request):
    car_list = Car.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    paginator = Paginator(car_list, 5)
    try:
        page=int(request.GET.get('page','1'))
    except:
        page=1
    try:
        cars= paginator.page(page)
    except(EmptyPage,InvalidPage):
        cars= paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request,"showcar.html",{'cars':cars})
```

this is savecar.html

```
  <div class="card-body">
            <form method="POST" action="/savecar" >
              {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="carname">Car Name</label>
                 <div class="col-sm-4">
                   {{ form.carname }}
                 </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="carmodel">carmodel</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                   {{ form.carmodel }}
                 </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="carimage">carimage</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                   {{ form.carimage }}
                 </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="price">price</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                   {{ form.price }}
                 </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="average">average</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                   {{ form.average }}
                 </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gear">gear</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                     {{ form.gear }}
                   </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="passengers">passengers</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                     {{ form.passengers }}
                   </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="type">type</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                     {{ form.type }}
                   </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Insurance">Insurance</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                     {{ form.Insurance }}
                   </div>
                  </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>&nbsp;
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/showcar">Back</a>
              </form>   
          </div>
```

**and yes i also install pillow**

Comment: If the solution below isn't working for you, please provide more information regarding your situation. Is there an error being returned? Is `form.is_valid()` returning False? Have you checked your browser's developer tools to verify that the request is being made properly?

Comment: when i click on submit button so that time it's image field is clear and not data are not going in database and also not create a media directory

Comment: @schillingt if you dont mind can i sent my project to you can you help me to solved my issue?? please can you sent your skypee id?

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form), you need to set the `enctype` on the `form` element and then pass in `request.FILES` to the form.

```
<form method="POST" action="/savecar" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And then in your views:

```
form = CarForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: i also try this but it's not working and also not created a media directory

Comment: Great, I was missing the `request.FILES`